# Type '[XYZ]!' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, migration, swift3

On the process of migrating an iOS app to Swift 3.0. Here is one issue I am facing.

First the relevant code:

```
struct OnlineBox {
    var vf1,vf2:CGFloat!
    var vs1:String!
}

var myOnlineInfo:[OnlineBox]!

func doSomeWork() {
   myOnlineInfo = [OnlineBox](repeating: OnlineBox(vf1: 0.0, vf2: 0.0, vs1: ""), count: 11)

   // below someInfoArray comes from querying a Core Data Entity:
   for item in someInfoArray {
       myOnlineInfo[(item.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vf1 = item.valueForKey("vf1") as! CGFloat
       myOnlineInfo[(item.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vf2 = item.valueForKey("vf2") as! CGFloat
       myOnlineInfo[(item.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vs1 = item.valueForKey("vs1") as! String
   }
}
```

Second the problem:

I am getting this mysterious error message, for the 3 lines inside the loop:

```
Type '[OnlineBox]!' has no subscript members
```

In other words an array has no subscript members. I don't quite get it.

How do I need to modify the code?

Comment: Show your someInfoArray. Is it like '[ [ "keyOne": 1, "vf1": 0.0 ... ],  [ "keyOne": 2, "vf1": 0.0 ] ... ]'?

Comment: I can show someInfoArray, but whatever it is "(item.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int)" should be an Int, the rest should not matter. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can now see where someInfoArray comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your someInfoArray is Array of Dictionary.

The 'item' is now instance of Dictionary which doesn't respond to valueForKey method.

So cast it to NSDictionary to respond valueForKey.

```
for item in someInfoArray {
    let i = item as NSDictionary
    myOnlineInfo[(i.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vf1 = i.valueForKey("vf1") as! CGFloat
    myOnlineInfo[(i.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vf2 = i.valueForKey("vf2") as! CGFloat
    myOnlineInfo[(i.valueForKey("keyOne") as! Int) - 1].vs1 = i.valueForKey("vs1") as! String
}
```

or simply,

```
for item in someInfoArray {
    myOnlineInfo[(item["keyOne"] as! Int) - 1].vf1 = item["vf1"] as! CGFloat
    myOnlineInfo[(item["keyOne"] as! Int) - 1].vf2 = item["vf2"] as! CGFloat
    myOnlineInfo[(item["keyOne"] as! Int) - 1].vs1 = item["vs1"] as! String
}
```

Comment: this answer put me on the right track, (and I finally made it work), so I click it as accepted. I still do not think the error message is appropriate though. It should clearly tell me that what I am providing as a subscript is not of the right type.

Comment: I agree that the error message doesn't tell the truth. Please file bug report to apple.